# Error 105 while sending jumbo ethernet udp frames, how to get rid of this error?

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I am trying to send UDP packets of size 8192 using a RAW socket, and can successfully send a few packets, but eventually I get error 105:

Below is my code:

```
/* Note: run this program as root user */

struct ifreq ifreq_c, ifreq_i, ifreq_ip;
int sock_raw;
unsigned char *sendbuff;


 #define DESTMAC0 0x00
 #define DESTMAC1 0x0c
 #define DESTMAC2 0x29
 #define DESTMAC3 0xb7
 #define DESTMAC4 0x20
 #define DESTMAC5 0x57

 #define destination_ip 192.168.95.175

int total_len = 0, send_len;

void get_eth_index()
{
    memset(&ifreq_i, 0, sizeof(ifreq_i));
    strncpy(ifreq_i.ifr_name, "ens33",IFNAMSIZ-1);
    if ((ioctl(sock_raw, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifreq_i)) < 0)
        printf("error in index ioctl reading");
    printf("index=%d\n", ifreq_i.ifr_ifindex);
}

void get_mac()
{
    memset(&ifreq_c, 0, sizeof(ifreq_c));
    strncpy(ifreq_c.ifr_name, "ens33",IFNAMSIZ-1);

    if ((ioctl(sock_raw, SIOCGIFHWADDR, &ifreq_c)) < 0)
       printf("error in SIOCGIFHWADDR ioctl reading");

    printf("Mac= %.2X-%.2X-%.2X-%.2X-%.2X-%.2X\n", (unsigned char)(ifreq_c.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[0]), (unsigned char)(ifreq_c.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[1]), (unsigned char)(ifreq_c.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[2]), (unsigned char)(ifreq_c.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[3]), (unsigned char)(ifreq_c.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[4]), (unsigned char)(ifreq_c.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[5]));

    printf("ethernet packaging start ... \n");

    struct ethhdr *eth = (struct ethhdr *)(sendbuff);
    eth->h_source[0] = (unsigned char)(ifreq_c.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[0]);
    eth->h_source[1] = (unsigned char)(ifreq_c.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[1]);
    eth->h_source[2] = (unsigned char)(ifreq_c.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[2]);
    eth->h_source[3] = (unsigned char)(ifreq_c.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[3]);
    eth->h_source[4] = (unsigned char)(ifreq_c.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[4]);
    eth->h_source[5] = (unsigned char)(ifreq_c.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[5]);

    eth->h_dest[0]    =  DESTMAC0;
    eth->h_dest[1]    =  DESTMAC1;
    eth->h_dest[2]    =  DESTMAC2;
    eth->h_dest[3]    =  DESTMAC3;
    eth->h_dest[4]    =  DESTMAC4;
    eth->h_dest[5]    =  DESTMAC5;

    eth->h_proto = htons(ETH_P_IP);  

    printf("ethernet packaging done.\n");

    total_len += sizeof(struct ethhdr);
}

void get_data()
{
    printf("\n total length in get data  %d", total_len);
    sendbuff[total_len++] = 0xAA;
    sendbuff[total_len++] = 0xBB;
    sendbuff[total_len++] = 0xCC;
    sendbuff[total_len++] = 0xDD;
    sendbuff[total_len++] = 0xEE;

    printf("\n total length in get data  %d", total_len);

    while (total_len < 8186)
        sendbuff[total_len++]= 0xAA;

    for (int i = 0; i < total_len; i++)
        printf ("\t %d ", sendbuff[i]);
}

void get_udp()
{
    struct udphdr *uh = (struct udphdr *)(sendbuff + sizeof(struct iphdr) + sizeof(struct ethhdr));

    uh->source = htons(23451);
    uh->dest = htons(23452);
    uh->check = 0;

    total_len += sizeof(struct udphdr);
    printf("\n total length %d :    ", total_len);
    get_data();
    int length = (total_len - sizeof(struct iphdr) - sizeof(struct ethhdr));
    printf(" \n udp size length %d ", length);
    uh->len = (length);
    printf("\n udp data length : %d", uh->len);
}

void get_ip()
{
    memset(&ifreq_ip, 0, sizeof(ifreq_ip));
    strncpy(ifreq_ip.ifr_name, "ens33", IFNAMSIZ-1);
    if (ioctl(sock_raw, SIOCGIFADDR, &ifreq_ip) < 0)
    {
        printf("error in SIOCGIFADDR \n");
    }

    printf(" IP  address  %s \n", inet_ntoa((((struct sockaddr_in*)&(ifreq_ip.ifr_addr))->sin_addr)));

    struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr*)(sendbuff + sizeof(struct ethhdr));
    iph->ihl = 5;
    iph->version = 4;
    iph->tos = 16;
    iph->id = 2048;
    iph->ttl = 64;
    iph->protocol = 17;
    iph->saddr = inet_addr(inet_ntoa((((struct sockaddr_in *)&(ifreq_ip.ifr_addr))->sin_addr)));
    iph->daddr = inet_addr("destination_ip"); // put destination IP address
    total_len += sizeof(struct iphdr);
    printf("\n get udp");
    get_udp();
    iph->tot_len = (total_len - sizeof(struct ethhdr));
    printf("\n IP data length : %d", iph->tot_len);
    iph->check = 0;
}

int main()
{
    sock_raw = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (sock_raw == -1)
    {
        printf("error in socket");
        return -1;
    }

    sendbuff = (unsigned char*)malloc(8192); // increase in case of large data.Here data is --> AA  BB  CC  DD  EE
    memset(sendbuff, 0, 8192);

    get_eth_index();  // interface number
    get_mac();
    printf("\n get IP");
    get_ip();
    printf("\n create  socket address");
    struct sockaddr_ll sadr_ll;
    sadr_ll.sll_ifindex = ifreq_i.ifr_ifindex;
    sadr_ll.sll_family = AF_INET;
    sadr_ll.sll_halen   = ETH_ALEN;
    sadr_ll.sll_addr[0]  = DESTMAC0;
    sadr_ll.sll_addr[1]  = DESTMAC1;
    sadr_ll.sll_addr[2]  = DESTMAC2;
    sadr_ll.sll_addr[3]  = DESTMAC3;
    sadr_ll.sll_addr[4]  = DESTMAC4;
    sadr_ll.sll_addr[5]  = DESTMAC5;

    int enable = 1;
    if (setsockopt(sock_raw, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &enable, sizeof(int)) < 0)
       error("setsockopt(SO_REUSEADDR) failed");

    printf("sending...\n");
    while (1)
    {
        send_len = sendto(sock_raw, sendbuff, total_len, 0, (const struct sockaddr*)&sadr_ll, sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll));
        if (send_len < 0)
        {
            sleep(1);
            printf("error in sending....sendlen=%d....errno=%d\n", send_len, errno);
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't want to use `SOCK_STREAM` and a TCP/IP connection, but I would only want to transmit UDP packets. I am running this on a Linux OS. If I change the packet size to 1518, I am able to transmit UDP data continuously, but for 8192 I get error 105.

Comment: Kindly format your code. It's unreadable.

Comment: Aside: There's no point in continuing after ```socket()``` has returned -1. Fail early, fail often, and fail well.

Comment: ```malloc``` can fail. Check its return code.

Comment: you never reset total_len

Comment: Thank you so much for all your answers. I did check and looks like malloc fails every single time. Why is malloc failing to allocate memory and why does it work without errors when i allocate 1518 bytes?

Comment: because you write beyond the end of your allocated buffer, you keep adding to total_len used as a buffer offset and never reset it after a send. YOu destroy the heap

Comment: yes you are right, thank you so much. resetting total_len worked. Thanks again.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @pm100 that should be posted as an answer rather than comments.

Answer (score 0):

because you write beyond the end of your allocated buffer, you keep adding to total_len used as a buffer offset and never reset it after a send. YOu destroy the heap

you need to add

```
    send_len = sendto(sock_raw, sendbuff, total_len, 0, (const struct sockaddr*)&sadr_ll, sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll));
    total_len = 0; // <<<<========
```